# Transparent Navigation Bar & Tabbar in iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to have a navigation bar and tabbar transparent to view background (reference image ==> https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vn8ef0p5lv1cw7/Required.png?dl=0). I am already setting background to view. But, I couldn't have Navigation Controller & Tabbar Controller transparent (reference image ==> https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfewqpwve78l4dq/Current.png?dl=0).

This is what I have tried before : 
1. Setting background color of Navigation Bar and Tabbar to null/clear color.
2. BarTintColor works for Navigation Bar but it only allows me to set color, cannot have clearcolor (makes it black when I tried)
3. Translucent property !

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to set transparent background images for navigation bar and tab bar. This will definitely solve your issue.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBar.png"];
    [navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Updated:**

```
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Comment: I cannot add image because device type (3.5, 4, 4.7 or 5.5) is not fixed, so image looks broken if I implement one

Comment: Take a 3x image and set the same. This will work. As it will automatically set the same image for all the devices.

Comment: Also try updated answer, accept if it works. If not, let me know. My pleasure mate :)

Comment: Proper way ? Let me see the current output.

Comment: Right. You needed transparent navigation bar right ? Now you just want to set backButton properties like fontColor n all. Thats it.

Comment: No first I want to fix this, it doesn't look attached :(

Comment: Good :) Happy coding :)

Comment: Accept my answer if you felt somewhere it helped you, and others can refer it. Thanks :)